# Most efficient multi-threaded object duplicate filtering (using custom key)?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, duplicates, parallel-processing

I'm writing a service client that recalls huge delimited strings containing individual records from a remote service.  Due to the size of these strings, I'm dividing the remote service calls up into chunks (date ranges) and looping over the date ranges in parallel to call the remote service and parse the data.  The problem is, 50%+ of the records are duplicates so I want filter those out...

Here's my current approach:

```
// We want to filter out duplicate markets by using the MarketId field...
HashSet<ParsedMarketData> exchangeFixtures = 
    new HashSet<ParsedMarketData>(
        new GenericEqualityComparer<ParsedMarketData, int>(pmd => pmd.MarketId));

DateTime[][] splitTimes = 
    SplitDateRange(startDate, endDate, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

// Effectively a Tasks.Parallel.ForEach call...
_parallel.ForEach(splitTimes, startEndTime =>
{
    DateTime start = startEndTime[0];
    DateTime end = startEndTime[1];

    string marketDataString = remoteServiceProxy.GetMarketData(start, end);
    IEnumerable<ParsedMarketData> rows = 
        _marketDataParser.ParseMarketData(marketDataString);

    foreach (ParsedMarketData marketDataRow in rows)
    {
        lock (_syncObj)
        {
            // Ignore the return value as we don't care 
            // if it gets added or not...
            marketDataList.Add(exchangeFixture);
        }
    }
});
```

Fundamentally, is a locked data structure (that finds duplicates) the most efficient approach to this problem or can it be improved?

It might be probably worth knowing that the majority (95%+) of the 'duplicate' items occur within each time bracket. I.e. if we're retrieving "Day A" and "Day B" in parallel, there won't be many (or any) duplicates between Day A and Day B (but many within each day - and in my solution, each thread).

Comment: Your solution seems like it won't be parallel at all.

Comment: @svick - Why is that?  The remote service proxy [webservice] is threadsafe and allows parallel calls - it's that call that takes the most time (although I still want to run the parsing in parallel too).

Comment: Because when you reach the final stage, only one thread can ever add to the result set.

Comment: That doesn't matter - the vast majority of the time is spent waiting for the webservice + parsing.  This happens in parallel - the results of which are added in a threadsafe way to the collection.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what is the question. You want to speed up adding to the collection, even though it “doesn't matter”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tune your code to take advantage of the concurrency opportunities in the data and service.  Sounds like one thread per day could be an option.

Actually seeing an improvement ought to be rare.  Multiple threads buy your more cpu cycles, not more Internet connections, network cards or service machines.  Odds are high that just two threads are optimal.  One to get the data from the service, another to process it.  Allowing these two operations to be overlapped, a thread-safe producer/consumer queue between them.  You could only get a benefit from more threads if the processing thread requires more time than the data retrieval thread.  Also a scenario that lets you easily profile the code, you can speedup the processing but not the retrieval.  You don't even need a profiler for a first estimate.  If the data processing thread doesn't burn 100% core then you're done.

Comment: I'd expect him to be able open dozens of internet connections on any decent machine, so dozens of threads for internet data fetch seem like a good idea if they are going to different places.  Given that the data rate from those dozens of connections isn't likely very high (what 1 mb per second sustained?), he might need only one thread to delete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data, and high chance of duplicates within each thread (and low chance of duplicates between threads) I decided to go with the following solution, it allows each thread to perform its stuff without impediment from locks and does a little filtering at the end on the caller thread to ensure the filtering is done correctly.

It also has the added benefit that the order in which the objects are returned from the service calls (date order) is maintained across threads so no need to sort it at the end.

```
public IEnumerable<Stuff> GetStuffs(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if (startDate >= endDate)
        throw new ArgumentException("startDate must be before endDate", "startDate");

    IDateRange dateRange = new DateRange(startDate, endDate);

    IDateRange[] dateRanges = _dateRangeSplitter.DivideRange(dateRange, TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).ToArray();

    IEnumerable<Stuff>[] resultCollections = new IEnumerable<Stuff>[dateRanges.Length];

    _parallel.For(0, dateRanges.Length, i =>
    {
        IDateRange splitRange = dateRanges[i];

        IEnumerable<Stuff> stuffs = GetMarketStuffs(splitRange);

        resultCollections[i] = stuffs;
    });

    Stuff[] marketStuffs = resultCollections.SelectMany(ef => ef).Distinct(ef => ef.EventId).ToArray();

    return marketStuffs;
}

private IEnumerable<Stuff> GetMarketStuffs(IDateRange splitRange)
{
    IList<Stuff> stuffs = new List<Stuff>();
    HashSet<int> uniqueStuffIds = new HashSet<int>();

    string marketStuffString = _slowStuffStringProvider.GetMarketStuffs(splitRange.Start, splitRange.End);

    IEnumerable<ParsedStuff> rows = _stuffParser.ParseStuffString(marketStuffString);

    foreach (ParsedStuff parsedStuff in rows)
    {
        if (!uniqueStuffIds.Add(parsedStuff.EventId))
        {
            continue;
        }

        stuffs.Add(new Stuff(parsedStuff));
    }
    return stuffs;
}
```